# Why isn't the dataContractSerializer not resolving the System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, app-config, datacontractserializer

I got the following exception when working with XMLs in a WCF application:

System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw
an exception while trying to deserialize the message:

After adding the following part of DataContractSerializer it doesn't work. Still getting the error. My app.config looks like this after adding DataContractSerializer:

```
configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Graph">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000000"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <bindings>

        <basicHttpBinding>

            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBrokerService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>

            </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://mx4p2/test1/test2.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_TestService" contract="Proxy.TestService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_TestService" behaviorConfiguration="Graph" />
    </client>



</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

bindingConfiguration should be the same with binding name. Take a look here :
[WCF Service - System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2d58cbf-ffde-4434-890d-73d71526a995/wcf-service-systemservicemodeldispatchernetdispatcherfaultexception?forum=wcf)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the exception simply by increasing the value of maxStringContentLength. No need for behaviors.